# Xpath or Importxml in google spreadsheet

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am having a trouble while fetching SERP (Search Engine Result) from yahoo to Google Sheets. I am trying to get **href of very first result** on this page.

Here is xpath:

```
//*[@id="yui_3_10_0_1_1474115100593_232"]
```

Here is my query : `site:linkedin.com/company/ 1011vc.com,TenEleven Ventures`

[image: Google search results snapshot]

But I am not getting href that I am looking to get. Can I get any help with this issue. :'(

Comment: can anybody help please? thanks :'(

Comment: See below - I also added an alternative formula for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just simplify your xpath to `//h3/a/@href` and then wrap it in trim to only give you the first result - also as far as formatting - I personally always end up using regexreplace to get the piece I want, and reformat it as an actual url:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(IMPORTXML(A1,"//h3/a/@href")),"(^.*linkedin.com%2fcompany%2f)(.*)(/RK.*)","http://linkedin.com/company/$2")
```

The regex basically groups the portions into 3 parts - 
1) The beginning of the string up until you reach the part that has linkedin listed - represented as `^.*linkedin.com%2fcompany%2f` since the results return as the encoded url string

2) the wildcard value for the unique id or slug of the company profile - `(.*)`

3) Then the portion following after it so it know where to stop: `(/RK.*)`

Using regexreplace, you can then specify that you want it to replace the whole string with the `2nd` capture group - represented by a `$2` - then just to come full circle I reappend the first half of the final url so that it is not encoded

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should a more general xpath based on a part of the search, something like:

```
//h3/a[contains(@href, ventures)]/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string(//b[start-with(@id, "yui")]/ancestor::a[1]/@href)
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles, not seems to be working... =IMPORTXML(A2,string(//a[text()="Ten Eleven Ventures | LinkedIn"]/@href))

Comment: the query for yahoo will become something like this https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0LEVzqFK91Xs9cAQn5XNyoA;_ylc=X1MDMjc2NjY3OQRfcgMyBGZyA3NmcARncHJpZAN5aHdhdkRSZlJMU2pDNW5heDYuT1ZBBG5fcnNsdAMwBG5fc3VnZwM0BG9yaWdpbgNzZWFyY2gueWFob28uY29tBHBvcwMwBHBxc3RyAwRwcXN0cmwDMARxc3RybAM2OARxdWVyeQNzaXRlJTNBbGlua2VkaW4uY29tJTJGY29tcGFueSUyRiUyMDEwMTF2Yy5jb20lMkNUZW5FbGV2ZW4lMjBWZW50dXJlcwR0X3N0bXADMTQ3NDExMjU1Nw--?p=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fcompany%2F+1011vc.com%2CTenEleven+Ventures&fr2=sb-top&fr=sfp

Comment: sorry for delay in response.. Well my formula looks something like this =IMPORTXML(A2,"//b[start-with(@id, "yui")]/ancestor::a[1]/@href") but i am not getting anything except an error in google doc .. . error message is "Formula Parse Error"

Comment: btw the reason your getting formula parse error is because you have to put single quotes around the id value , in your case it was `yui`